# Finding equation whose roots are square of the original but intially some of them were negative .

Tags: transformation, cubics

Consider a cubic  given as $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ which has roots $\alpha,-\beta,-\gamma$ , we need to find cubic equation whose roots are $\alpha^2 ,\beta^2 , \gamma^2$ is it possible to get it by transformation of roots ? By letting √y = x and substituting it ? If its not possible does vietas work? As such i tried both but was not able to fully get the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You know that your cubic is $f_1:=(x-\alpha)(x+\beta)(x+\gamma)$, you want to compute the cubic $f_2:=(x-\alpha^2)(x-\beta^2)(x-\gamma^2)$.
By the description I gave above of your cubic you know $a,b,c$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, so you are asking if it is possible to describe the coefficients of the second equation in terms of these coefficients.

I suggest you using CoCoa or a program like this:
Work in $\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,a',b',c']$ with the term order of elimination (lex term order for example) s.t. a',b',c' have the lowest weight and the give the highest weight to the coefficients $a,b,c$.

Now set the ideal $I$ given by the relations between coefficients $a,b,c,a',b',c'$ and the roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and the squares. Compute the representative element for $a',b',c'$ in this setting.

If there is some relation between $a,b,c$ and $a',b',c'$ Cocoa will find it for you ;)

Otherwise I see only the pencil and paper solution!

Answer (score 0):

Let mark $\beta=-\beta$ and $\gamma=-\gamma$. This does not influence equation that we need to obtain. Using Vieta's theorem: $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-a, \alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=b, \alpha\beta\gamma=-c$$

Then we need to express $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=A$, $\alpha^2\beta^2+\alpha^2\gamma^2+\beta^2\gamma^2=B$ and $\alpha^2\beta^2\gamma^2=C$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$.

One can easily show that
$$a^2=A+2b, c^2=C, b^2=B+2\cdot(-a)\cdot(-c)=B+2ac$$
$$A=a^2-2b, C=c^2, B=b^2-2ac$$

The resulting equation is $$x^3-(a^2-2b)x^2+(b^2-2ac)x-c^2=0$$

Comment: Are you sure its correct ? as such $\alpha-\beta-\gamma = -a $ not all are positive and simialrily while squaring some terms would be negative and some positive

Comment: Why we need to see at positiveness and negativeness of terms? Independent of positiveness of $x$ and $y$ formula $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$ is correct. Suppose solutions of original equation are $\alpha$, $-\beta$, $-\gamma$ and $\beta_1=-\beta$, $\gamma_1=-\gamma$. Then solutions are $\alpha$, $\beta_1$, $\gamma_1$. Solutions of resulting equation are $\alpha^2$, $\beta_1^2=\beta^2$ and $\gamma_1^2=\gamma^2$.

Comment: See first sentence in my answer, where I redefine $\beta$ and $\gamma$ in such way that roots of original equation are $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$.